# Importing and exporting file in React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[THE ERROR MESSAGE I AM GETTING ON MY DEVICE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwIgn.jpg)Iam working on React Native.As I import my other react native file(i.e component1.js) into the index.android.js file.
It's giving an error
**"Expected a component class,got[object Object]".**

component1.js

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import {AppRegistry,Text,View} from 'react-native';

  export default class component1 extends Component {
      render() {
        return( 
           <View>
             <Text>This is component1</Text>
           </View>
        );
      } 
  }

  AppRegistry.registerComponent('component1', () => component1);
```

index.android.js

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import {AppRegistry,Text,View} from 'react-native';
  import component1 from'./app/Components/component_a/component1'

  export default class myapp extends Component {
      render() {
           return (
                 <View>
                     <component1 />
                  </View>
           );
      }
  }

  AppRegistry.registerComponent('myapp', () => myapp);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you define multiple AppRegistry in child and parent file. Remove `AppRegistry.registerComponent('component1', () => component1);` in component1.js, you don't need it . Just declare in the root component.

From [RN](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appregistry.html) docs.

> AppRegistry should be required early in the require sequence to make sure the JS execution environment is setup before other modules are required.